# list of ids - ALM API Automation

Tags: java, xml, api, nodes, alm

i am doing api automation of hp-alm using rest assured n java.For test cases with multiple runs, im getting the below response in xml format.I want to know the list of id attributes with its values.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zHx23.png)

```
RequestSpecification httpRequest10 = RestAssured.given().cookies(loginCookies).cookies(sessionCookies).queryParam("query", "{cycle-id["+cycleId+"];test-id["+testCaseId+"]}");

        Response testRunId = httpRequest10.request(Method.GET,"/qcbin/rest/domains/"+domain+"/projects/"+project+"/runs");
                String testRunIdResponseBody = testRunId.getBody().asString();
                //logger.info("testRunId Response Body is =>  " + testRunIdResponseBody);//test run details in xml format
                statusCode = testRunId.getStatusCode();
                //logger.info("The testRunId status code recieved: " + statusCode);
                String stepID= testRunId.xmlPath().from(testRunIdResponseBody).get("**.find {it.@Name == 'id'}.Value");
                List<String> runIds = testRunId.xmlPath().from(testRunIdResponseBody).getList("**.find {it.@Name == 'id'}.Value");
                logger.info("stepID"+stepID);
```

Using the above code im able to the first id but not list of ids

Comment: In which form do you get the answer? Is it org.w3c.dom.Document, some JAXB class or just string? Could you provide some code with your attempts to parse response? It would help to give a correct answer.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zHx23.png i have provided thescreenshot of the xml

Comment: That's not enough. I can write code which parses this XML as a string or as file and extracts list of ids, but  the solution may not be applicable for you, when it is parsed in some other way. That's why it would be better provide more information.

Comment: i have provided the code. is it sufficient or do u need any other inputs?

Comment: Try to use `**.findAll` instead of `**.find`

Comment: Thank you @AlexandraDudkina. It worked. Can u tell me a course / website from where i can learn about xml parsing

Comment: Glad to help. I added  the answer with the same solution. Could you mark it as accepted?

Comment: I used "XML in a Nutshell" by Elliotte Rusty Harold and W. Scott Means and "Beginning XML" by Joe Fawcett. Both books are not new, but provide solid foundation for XML based technologies. Course "XML and XML Schema Definition in Easy Steps" on udemy is not bad as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose `**.find` should be replaced with `**.findAll`:

```
List<String> runIds = testRunId.xmlPath().from(testRunIdResponseBody).getList("**.findAll {it.@Name == 'id'}.Value");
```